# How to easily rename voice memos in iTunes

Tags: iphone, itunes, macos, voice-memo

Recorded by native Voice Memo app on iPhone 5, and then sync to iTunes. But found those displayed name of voice memos that are set when I was recording are different with real file names in  iTunes after sync.

I have dozens of voice memo. How to easily rename real names with these displayed name that I want to have?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, but I found when I used iTunes to create an mp3 version of the file, the mp3 had the title I had set previously.

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question asked.